# Why images at Github in markdown formatted file on are blurred?

Tags: html, image, git, github, markdown

I have uploaded images (jpg and png) to github and used them in markdown formatted file here (first 2 images):
https://github.com/vasili111/testRepo/blob/master/github_question.md

Third and fourth images are inserted with html tag.

In link above in browser images are blurred. But they are not blurred when I access images from browser directly as here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vasili111/testRepo/master/images_for_github/3.png
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vasili111/testRepo/master/images_for_github/3.jpg

**Questions:**

1. Why images are getting blurred?
2. How to use images in markdown formatted text without blur effect?

Comment: Why downvotes? Please make comment about the reason of downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because they are rendered at a different size. The markdown-formatted ones are stretched to fit the screen; in your case, they are a bit too wide and have to be narrowed down by a few pixels, causing the blurring effect.

There's probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: But if I add images in markdown formatted file with html img tag where I also set the width and height of image to original image ones there is also blur effect. You think that in that case html img tags width and height is also ignored?

Comment: Probably. Can you post an example?

Comment: I edited the https://github.com/vasili111/testRepo/blob/master/github_question.md . First two ones are with markdown and third and forth with html img tag.

Comment: Yeah, GitHub automatically adds a `max-width` style that constricts your image. The only thing you can do is use smaller images.